# How can we prove that kruskal wallis test and jonckheere test is equivalent to wilcoxon rank sum test?

Tags: nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, kruskal-wallis-test, friedman-test

How can we prove that kruskal-Wallis test and Jonckheere test is equivalent to Wilcoxon rank sum test when k = 2?
And how can we prove that Friedman test and Page test is equivalent to sign test when k = 2?

Comment: They're not equivalent in general. You would need to restrict consideration to the situations where those tests all apply at the same time, otherwise you'd be stuck with answering questions like "how do I do a rank sum test with 3 groups?" and discovering that Jonckheere is not equivalent to Kruskal-Wallis for three groups.

Comment: i forgot to comment that I was referring to when k equals to 2

Comment: An edit to make that explicit rather than implied would help your question.